# Python string to dictionary

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, import

Problem appending new records to variable/list (dictionary).

I have created a program (adressbook) and imported a .csv file (headers are, name, lastname, street, etc).
I've use csvDictreader and next i've added the adresses to a empty list. Now i can search for adresses. But i've got a problem with adding new records to the list. I can add a new record, but it doesnt seems to add the new record in the wright way. Cause when I want to print the new record it says: Type error, 'set'object is not subscriptable.

In the code i've added the last 'For loop' returns a error. Probably i'm not adding the new record to the list in the wright way. I can use some help. (yes, i'm new to Python :-)

```
import sys
import csv

filename = "adresses.csv"
adressbook = []

with open(filename) as f:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in csv_reader:
        adressbook.append(row)

for row in adressbook:
    print(row['lastname'])

value = input("lastname: ")
adressbook.append({value})

for row in adressbook:
    print(row)

for row in adressbook:
    print(row['lastname'])
```

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14vRE.jpg)

Comment: Welcome krukkie, please can you add the error details as test rather than an image. Also I recommend you take a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
value = input("lastname: ")
adressbook.append({value})
```

appends to the `addressbook` list a **set** containing one element `value`. When you write later:

```
for row in adressbook:
    print(row['lastname'])
```

The last row is simply `{value}` and you get an error because you can't get a value associated to the key `lastname` from a set:

```
>>> {"tobie"}["lastname"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

You should only append `dict`s and not `set`s to the list. To append a new row to the book, you should write:

```
value = input("lastname: ")
adressbook.append({"lastname": value})
```

Obviously, this will be an almost empty row (no name, street, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Appending the record like this was the solutione.
adressbook.append(OrderedDict([("lastname", value[0].lower()),
                ("name", value[1].lower())